# Deep semantic segmenation and conditional random field

Tags: crf

i found the idea of combining the deep semantic segmentation model with the conditional random field getting very popular ... is their any library or resources for the CRFs code in tensorflow? since my deep semantic model is written in tensor flow and just would like to integrate it with the CRF for further boundary refinement...